# Rails 3.2.3 with spork does not recognize helper methods in cucumber tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, spork

I have a application that is using rails 3.2.3 and spork 1.0.0rc2.
 When I run my cucumber test I get:

```
ActionView::Template::Error: undefined local variable or method `page_title'
```

Where page_title is defined in my application helper. I am not sure what broke them as it was working until the last bundle update.

Anyone having the same issue?

Comment: What gems were updated before the issue appeared?

Comment: Is this helper call inside a view that's used by devise? I've a similar problem and I suspect its because the view is rendered by the devise gem and somehow doesn't have the helpers.

Comment: @Malte how did you solved it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To fix this issue add these below lines in Spork.prefork block

```
full_names = Dir["#{Rails.root}/app/helpers/*.rb"]

full_names.collect do |full_name|
    include Object.const_get(File.basename(full_name,'.rb').camelize)
end
```

Comment: I was hoping this would fix this problem for me.  I added the code to my prefork block.  Now I'm getting the following error when I try to start sprok:    uninitialized constant ApplicationHelper in `const_get'

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this thread https://github.com/sporkrb/spork-rails/issues/6#issuecomment-11105681 there are two solutions for this problem

Answer (score 1):

People has been reporting something alike for rails 3.1 when using spork: https://github.com/sporkrb/spork/issues/109

Basically, they tell you to use this:

```
Spork.trap_method(Rails::Application::RoutesReloader, :reload!)
```

I use rails 3.1 but that did not solve my problems. I'm still looking for an answer.